# File/data recovery

Tags: r, data-recovery, file-recovery

Very specific question.
I was storing a copy of my data in the system folder of a package. Made it easier to run from system.file(). Unfortunately, I accidentally reinstalled the package, and my personal files were "deleted" when R reinstalled the package. They vanished after reinstalled. I searched for the files in my system, but only the shortcut of where they used to be are found.

1. Are the copies of my data actually deleted?
2. If not, how can I recover them?

Comment: afaik the only way back is if you have a backup, sorry. better to store your files somewhere you manage; [RStudio projects](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-RStudio-Projects) are nice for keeping all your code and data organized.

Comment: Yeah. Those files are gone. You should never interact directly with the contents of the R library folder. Unless you have a back-up of your entire system elsewhere, you are out of luck.

Comment: I have my original data in a not R related folder, just wanted to see if I could get the other ones back. Thanks though!